# In Python Flask, better way to manage decorators?

Tags: python, flask

I'm starting have this issue pop up in all my routes in Python Flask:

```
@defaults.app.route('/<path:path>')
@forceUpdate
@FlaskLogin.login_required
@gzipped
def serve_page(path):
    try:
        resp = flask.send_from_directory(defaults.APP_STATIC, path)
        return resp
    except Exception:
        return flask.render_template("index.html")
```

Is there a better way to do this?

The `forceUpdate` decorator forces a redirect based upon a flag on a file system.

Login requires the user to be logged in.

And Gzip... gzips the response.

I have about 20 routes so far and its getting ugly having all these combinations of decorators.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm wondering. If there's a better way. Just trying to improve what I do. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new decorator that applies the others:

```
from functools import reduce

_common = (gzipped, FlaskLogin.login_required, forceUpdate)
def common_decorators(f):
    return reduce(lambda f, dec: dec(f), _common, f)
```

Then use just that one decorator:

```
@defaults.app.route('/<path:path>')
@common_decorators
def serve_page(path):
    ...
```